# Repetitive "Google failed" popup

Tags: system-error

I have a Nokia 3.4 (Android 10) for over a month now. This morning this repetitive error window keeps popping up. It opens and closes so fast that I don't have the time to select anything - in fact, it's so fast that the video capture is not able to capture all cases!

[image: Video capture]

This is a static capture of one of those error windows:

[image: static picture of the error]

Things I have already tried without success:

- Shutdown and reboot
- "Clean cache" and "clean data" of the Google app
- Block notifications for the Google app

The only way I was able to "fix" this was by disabling the Google app. But I would rather not...

Should I just do a factory reset?

Comment: Looks like this is a global issue caused by Google's update very recently. While the dupe isn't "answered" yet (there's a helpful comment there), I have to close it to centralize the info. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @AndrewT. Oops, I tried to find dups, but could not find any... Btw, in mine phone, the issue stopped - I am unsure why - it stopped after I enabled/disabled the Google app and rebooted a couple of times...

Comment: I think Google has pushed the fix. Also covered on XDA Forums: [It’s not just you: Google App is crashing for many Android users](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-app-crashing-android/)